# Adding multiple folders from different path to a single zip folder

Tags: python

I have two folders in different path lets say path1/file1 and path2/file2. I want to zip the both the files in a single zip folder. Is there any way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command as below

```
"zip -r total.zip pathoffolder1 pathoffolder2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `arcname="..."`, when writing to a `Zipfile` to create a new directory in the zip:

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile


def zipFlat(files, zipFolder, outFile):
    zipFolder = Path(zipFolder)
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(outFile, 'w')
    for file in files:
        filename = Path(file).name
        arcPath = zipFolder / Path(filename)
        zipf.write(file, arcname=str(arcPath))


filesToZip = ['/tmp/foo/bar/R.txt', '/tmp/foo/baz/Z.txt']
zipFlat(filesToZip, 'myArchiveDir', '/tmp/archive.zip')
```

The resulting zip file are saved within 'myArchiveDir':

```
# unzip -l archive.zip                                                                                                                        
Archive:  archive.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  01-15-2019 16:18   myArchiveDir/R.txt
        0  01-15-2019 16:18   myArchiveDir/Z.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```